# Sort by associated attribute count on inverse associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Association sort question again :)

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a user with many challenges through inverse associations on the total amount of sent and received challenges in total.

Here's the association code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Model

  has_many :sent_challenges, class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: :challenger_id, inverse_of: :challenger
  has_many :received_challenges, class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: :opponent_id, inverse_of: :opponent


  class << self
    def in_order
      # return users sorted by amount of sent + received challenges
      order("…")
    end
  end

end
```

I want the `.in_order` method to return the users sorted by total challenges.